# Paperclip won't save image in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am trying to use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) with my Rails app to add an avatar to a user but it won't save my image or update the database column when creating the user.

This is what the model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar
```

And the registerform in haml:

```
- form_for :user, @user, :url => { :action => "signup" }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
 ...
 ...
      %li
        %div{:class => "header"} Profilepicture
        %div{:class => "input"}
          = f.file_field :avatar
```

And when I look in the log this is what is being passed to the "signup" action:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"signup", "controller"=>"user/register",      "user"=>{"name"=>"Micke Lisinge", "birthmonth"=>"07", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "nickname"=>"lisinge", "avatar"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20100426-3076-1x04oxy-0>, "gen"=>"m", "birthday"=>"23", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "birthyear"=>"1992", "email"=>"lisinge@gmail.coma"}}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

Paperclip says it is saving the template but when I look in the `public` folder in my app it has created a `system` but the `system` folder is empty.

So it seems like it isn't saving the picture to the folder.

It gets handled by the form and saved in my `/tmp` folder.

Maybe you guys have any tips or know what this problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work.

I had to add `:avatar` to `attr_accessible` in my **user model**.

Posting this here and hopes that it helps someone sometime :)

Thanks guys for your help

Comment: i have the same problem, i tried adding the attr_accessible but it still dosent save correctly and shows a missing message when i try load the picture. this is very frustrating

Comment: Try to set the :path option. It might help

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set :multipart => true in your form declaration. This has bitten me once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
has_attached_file :asset, :url  => "/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

FYI, This code actually saved my files in the root directory of my machine "/" as the :rails_root param was failing. This is on Rails 3.0.0.rc

Answer (score 0):

First check, if `path` is correct for the created attachment. You can use `avatar.path` to determine that. if it is not returning correct path, may be someone is overriding the default `paperclip` path?

Also check, if public/system is writable by the user as which you are running the application server.

Comment: running as root so it should be able to write

Comment: i get `can't convert nil into String` when using `@user.avatar.path`

Comment: Its almost always useful to post complete backtrace.

Comment: But it doesnt even save to the database

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the :path option

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ':rails_root/public/system/:id.:extension'
```